# How to constrain my function to only accept type compatible with empty object?

Tags: typescript

I have this code:

```
export type Data = Record<string, unknown> 

const x: Data = {}
```

This one is OK, so an empty object can be seen as a WizardryFormData.

```
export const createManager = <FormData extends Data>(
    initial: FormData,
) => {

    const x: FormData = {};
}
```

This one is KO. TS complains with `'{}' is assignable to the constraint of type 'FormData', but 'FormData' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Data'.(2322).

I understand that FormData, when inferred in the `createManager` function can be something which extends Data and both, is not compatible with an empty object.

But how to constrain my function to only accept FormData which is compatible with {} ?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=14&pln=5&pc=27#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAiBDGG4F44BKwAxtACYA8AzjFAJYB2A5gDRwCuDA1gxAO4MAfHABQI0gxpwQALnRYc+AN4BfMaEiw4EqcSjAswALIYGGJsCh44FAGLQAtpmxxQMYAzJV52QQAoROCC4RjoYOgwAGzl7KCcFFhEASjxhJTFg7QhJeFk4WPiXZRUAbhE1ESA)

Comment: Assuming it's the question inside the post: you can't really do this with generics.  It would require that TS support *lower bounds* as requested in [ms/TS#14520](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14520); these can be simulated for callers, like [this](//tsplay.dev/WKpOGw), but it still doesn't help you. And I doubt it's what you want, anyway.  If your generic is supposed to be something *to which* you can assign the empty object, it's going to be very hard to call.  I wonder what your actual underlying use case is; with this as given I'd say [don't use generics](//tsplay.dev/WJAXvm).

Comment: So how would you like to proceed here?

Comment: Thanks @jcalz. Maybe generics is not appropriate. My real use case, is that I have a reducer function, which can reset the object. So somewhere I try to reset to {} and the compiler complains on it.

Comment: Can you show a bit more of the use case in the code if you want a suggestion?  If the value will *temporarily* be `{}` but you know it will *eventually* be `T` (which is hard to know for sure) then you can just *assert* that it's `T` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wjDXbm), but keep in mind that's a *claim* you're making and not something the compiler can help verify anymore.  And if you're wrong about your assertion then you'll have to deal with the consequences.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to use the `Partial` utility type?

```js
export const createManager = <FormData extends Data>(
    initial: FormData,
) => {

    const x: Partial<FormData> = {};
}
```